# MVC5 Single Sign On with AD and Windows Auth

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, active-directory, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I am Devloping a MVC5 Intranet Web Page and for Auth i want a single sign on with windows auth.

What I have so far is, Configured Windows Auth in IIS and Configured Windows Auth in my Web.config

For my AD I assume, I only need a Membershipprovider config in my web.config and than i can use the [Authorize Roles=""] attribute?

Now when I am trying to log in my Page, the IIS always prompt for credentials, I just dont get it why this not working. Maybe my knowledge is just completely wrong about Single Sign On in a WebPage.

Any Help on this? Maybe just some Page explain all that stuff? Couldn't finy anything to help me on this.

Comment: It will always ask for credentials except if you're using Internet Explorer.

Comment: It does also prompt in IE

Comment: Just needed to mark the site as intranet